# How to focus in a RecyclerView with TalkBack (TTS - Acessibility)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, focus, accessibility

I have the following xml (some attributes were omitted for simplicity):

```xml
<FrameLayout>

  <RecyclerView 
       android:id="@+id/list"
       android:focusable="true"
       android:contentDescription="Some content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

When I activate TalkBack (TTS) to test accessibility in my app, I want to be able to click in the RecyclerView (in any item on it) so the whole RecyclerView gets focused and its content description gets read.

I've tryed:

- removed any `android:focusable="true"` from the items in the list, alsto there is no TextView in them, so TTS cannot read them.
- added `android:focusable="true"` to the RecyclerView. Even by making the view larger than its children and being able to click directly on it, it was not receiving any focus at all.
- was able to "focus" on the RecyclerView by wrapping it with a FrameLayout and adding `android:focusable="true"` to it, so the FrameLayout was being focused giving the impression the whole list was focused (but this is more of a workaround).

Comment: do you still need help with this? if so, the solution can be achieve in some steps:
using `android:descendantFocusability` and using `isFocusableInTouchMode`. If you wanna I can post a solution... but it has been 2 months since you asked xD

Comment: @MiguelHincapieC feel free to post a solution :) I did not even found a solution for this one yet.